# How to know a react link component has been clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to capture when a `<Link>` is clicked in the component? The first time you click the link, the page loads fine. But when you click the same link a second time, it doesn't reload data. This is the standard result, as it only rerenders when the state/props have changed, but I want to reload new data from the server when the page is revisited.

I've tried using `componentDidUpdate` but that just ends in an infinite loop. I'm looking for a way to know when `react-router-dom`  has been used and query the server for fresh data.

I've listed the broken down code fragments used below.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/users" component={Users}/>
</Switch>
```

```
<Link to={"/users"}>Users</Link>
```

```
class Users extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
        console.log('componentDidMount');
    }

    componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    }
    getData() {
        axios.get(this.props.table.url).then(response => {
            this.setState({ users: response.data, loading: false})
        })
    }

    render() {
        return( ... )
    }
}
```

Comment: when you press the `Link` button, the route has got changed to 'user', every time you change the route, the `componentDidMount` will call. if it's not working on your application, I suggest you create a codesandbox.

Comment: another question, the `Link` button is on another page (route), so when you click it, the route has changedd to `/user` so how can click the `Link` for a second time?  is there on the `user` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've a couple options to "conditionally" handle calling the `getData` only when accessing the component via the link.

1. Use some local state to hold a React key value for the link and to send as route state to be checked in the routed component.

   Example:

   ```
   import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

   ...

   const [linkKey, setLinkKey] = useState(uuidV4());

   ...

   <Link
     key={linkKey}
     to={{ pathname: "/users", state: { key: linkKey } }}
     onClick={() => setLinkKey(uuidV4())}
   >
     Users
   </Link>
   ```

   Users

   ```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     if (prevProps.location.state?.key !== this.props.location.state?.key) {
       this.getData();
     }
   }
   ```

   - Pros: Doesn't remount the target routed component. Doesn't push duplicate paths into the history.
   - Cons: Adds more moving parts, i.e. local state and updaters.
2. Use a `Redirect` from a path with a "random" path parameter to the "/users" path.

   ```
   import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

   ...

   <Link to={generatePath("/users/:key", { key: uuidV4() })}>Users</Link>

   ...

   <Switch>
     <Redirect from="/users/:key" to="/users" />
     <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
   </Switch>
   ```

   - Pros: Less moving parts.
   - Cons: Remounts `Users` components each time. Pushes each new "instance" into the history stack.

[image: Edit how-to-know-a-react-link-component-has-been-clicked]

Comment: I ended up using `+ new Date()` to identify a new click, it seemed like less overhead than importing another library.  Would you suggest there be a reason to use the uuid over a timestamp?

Comment: @Bradmage Not a strong reason. GUID's (`uuid`) will guarantee uniqueness, but a timestamp is likely sufficiently unique enough for your needs. A lot of projects I work with already use `uuid` so it's an easy goto.